# Store RSA-SHA256 from openssl in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, openssl

I need to save `RSA-SHA256` keys from the code below into mysql table, which is the optimal column type?

```
$configargs = array(
    "digest_alg" => 'RSA-SHA256',
    "private_key_bits" => 4096
);
$res = openssl_pkey_new($configargs);
openssl_pkey_export($res, $privKey, NULL, $configargs);
$publickey = openssl_pkey_get_details($res)['key'];
```

Comment: So what's the question here? What issue you are facing? What is expected?

Comment: The problem is that the key is truncated, I wanted to understand what is the right operation to store the key

Comment: `BLOB type` is the best column datatype for storing this kind of data.

Comment: I will consider it to save in a `text` column datatype. Much better than that is to save it into a text file

Comment: @Anant-Alivetodie 
I would agree with you regarding a single key, unfortunately in this case it happens for every user and has to be compared via a return from mysql

Comment: @SimoneRossaini then `text` ,`mediumtext`,`largetext`,`blob` any one can work.